# Как в C# программно запустить *.exe файл с правами администратора?

Tags: c#, winapi

Здравствуйте уважаемые гуру.
У меня такой вопрос:
Как в C# программно запустить *.exe файл с правами администратора?
За ранние спасибо

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Для начала необходимо добавить файл манифеста в проект (Проект -> Добавить новый элемент -> Файл манифеста приложения), открыть его и найти следующую строчку:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

На ее место поставить:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

profit