# Как изменить расширение файла .txt в формат .ini который находится в "C:\"?

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь поменять расширение файла из `.txt` в формат `.ini`:

```
private void button1_Click() {
    System.IO.File.Move(@"C:\file.txt", @"C:\file.ini");
}
```

Но при нажатии на `button1_Click` выходит ошибка:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Отказано в доступе по данному
>   пути."

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос как положено, ибо я зашел сюда увидев "Как изменить расширение файла", захожу, читаю текст, а там "Отказано в доступе". Так у вас отказано в доступе или вы хотите изменить расширение? Определитесь... Также добавьте свои попытки (код), которым вы это делаете, а также сам файл, где он у вас "С:\" или все же "AppData"? Как видите вопросов много, чего явно быть не должно...

Comment: Прошу прощения, я здесь новенький)) в процессе научусь правильно задавать вопросы)! 
Вот собственно сам код:
private void button1_Click
System.IO.File.Move(@"C:\file.txt", @"C:\file.ini");
При нажатии на button1_Click выходит ошибка System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Отказано в доступе по данному пути."

Comment: Под вопросом кнопка "Править", нажимаете и редактируете сам вопрос. По поводу ошибки, подумайте сами, почему отказано в доступе? Наверно потому, что диск C является системным и требует права администратора для редактирования файлов, либо ваш файл занят чем либо. Запустите вашу программу от администратора.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо)! А можно как-нибудь прописать это дело в самом коде так, чтобы программа запускалась уже со всеми правами? Сам файл ничем не занят, так как он мной и был создан. Я просто хочу написать программу по изменению типов расширений со всеми правами

Comment: А тут я вам посоветую научиться искать. Первая ссылка по запросу [c# start application as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator) либо поиск через [RuSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/295422).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо Вам Большое;)))!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. диск C:\ скорее всего системный - то вашей программе не хватает прав на изменение файлов (удаление, запись).

Вариант №1 - попробуйте не в корневой директории сделать операцию переименования файла или на другом диске.

Вариант №2 - попробуйте программу (или Visual Studio, если Вы проверяете под отладкой) под правами администратора запустить